# Aplicar função lamba para uma subtração e soma python

Tags: python, pandas

Como aplicar a função lambda para executar duas operações, por exemplo:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'temperatura':[42.31, 38.51, 39.93, 46.63, 46.50]})
df
```

O que gostaria era de transformar essas temperaturas em ºC, usando a fórmula:

```
(temperatura - 32 / 1,8)
```

Consegui realizar com duas funções lambda:

```
df2['temperatura'] = df2['temperatura'].apply(lambda x: x - 32)
df2['temperatura'] = df2['temperatura'].apply(lambda x: x / 1.8)
```

Queria saber se é possível fazer a operação toda somente com um lambda?

Answer (score 8):

Evite usar os métodos [`dataframe.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) ou [`series.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html), pois são lentos, o Pandas não faz julgamentos ou otimizações sobre a natureza da função usada e que portanto aplica iterativamente (*loops*) a função usada a série conforme necessário.

Embora iterações forneçam uma utilidade maravilhosa, cada iteração sobre um elemento é essencialmente uma única etapa na rota por todos os elementos da coleção. Este processamento passo a passo é útil quando a ordem da operação é estritamente importante.

Quando a ordem de processamento não importa o Pandas oferece um recurso mais poderoso: o processamento vetorizado. Métodos NumPy e Pandas permitem a vetorização, e quase sempre funciona mais rápido, pois o tempo de execução é constante ou cresce em uma taxa muito mais lenta com um número maior de elementos.

A vetorização se aproveita do fato das CPUs terem conjuntos de instruções "vetoriais" ou "SIMD" que aplicam a mesma operação simultaneamente a um conjunto de dados. Então vetorização é o processo de reescrever uma ação iterativa de modo que, em vez de processar um elemento de uma coleção por vez, sejam aproveitadas a operações "SIMD" para aplicar essa operação simultaneamente a vários elementos dessa coleção.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'temperatura':[42.31, 38.51, 39.93, 46.63, 46.50]})


df['temperatura vetorizada'] = (df['temperatura'] - 32) / 1.8         #Converção de ºF para ºC com operação vetorizada.

df['temperatura não vetorizada'] = df['temperatura'].apply(lambda x: (x - 32) / 1.8)  #Converção de ºF para ºC com operação iterativa.

print(df);
#   temperatura  temperatura vetorizada  temperatura não vetorizada
#0        42.31                5.727778                    5.727778
#1        38.51                3.616667                    3.616667
#2        39.93                4.405556                    4.405556
#3        46.63                8.127778                    8.127778
#4        46.50                8.055556                    8.055556
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [replit.com](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/temperaturavetorizada#main.py)

Como sugestão [essa palestra](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nxWginnBklU) sobre ganho de performance com vetorização em Pandas e Numpy</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Consegui depois de algumas tentativas:

```
df2['temperatura'] = df2['temperatura'].apply(lambda x: (x - 32) / 1.8)
```