# Atualizar coluna de dataframe no Python

Tags: python

Eu gostaria aplicar uma operação de eliminação de espaços de cada elemento da coluna item do dataframe aplicando a funcao Converte em cada um dos elementos

```
def Converte(x):
    x = x.replace(" ","")
    return x

products_list = ['10 0', '10 1', '10 2', '10 3', '10 4']
df = pd.DataFrame (products_list, columns = ['item'])
```

No inicio eu tenho:

```
    item
0   10 0
1   10 1
2   10 2
3   10 3
4   10 4
```

No final eu teria no mesmo dataframe

```
    item
0   100
1   101
2   102
3   103
4   104
```

Como eu poderia fazer ?

Comment: Já tentou algo como `df['item'] = df['item'].apply(Converte)`?

Comment: muito obrigado !! funcionou ! era exatamente isso que eu procurava. Obrigado

Comment: voce pode postar como resposta para eu poder dar os pontos para voce ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dê preferência por usar métodos vetorizados, pois são mais rápidos.

```
df["item"] = df["item"].str.replace(" ", "")
```

Comment: Caso tenha oportunidade, veja a comparação das possibilidades de atualização do dataframe [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52673285/performance-of-pandas-apply-vs-np-vectorize-to-create-new-column-from-existing-c)

Comment: obrigado, boa recomendação, mas minha pergunta foi simplificada, na verdade eu tenho de fazer várias manipulações nessa rotina Converte. Eu simplifique colocando uma simples troca de espaços para focar na minha duvida.

Comment: @AntonioAbrantes que bom que resolveu o problema.

Comment: a melhor resposta foi dado por Woss, mas ele postou em comentário e não como uma resposta

Comment: @AntonioAbrantes, antes de considerar o uso do `apply` leia essa resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/564425/137387